# How can I add an event observer for each element I find on the page?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events

I'm working with Prototype on a script to detect all Select Tags under a Div and then add an event/observer on each one!

Here is the code to find the Elements I need:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
  var tab=$("product-options-wrapper").descendants();
  var attCode=[];
  var j=0;

  for (i=0;i<tab.length;i++) {
    if (tab [i].tagName =="SELECT") {
      attCode[j++]=tab[i].id
    }
  }
});
```

I have all the Ids I need.
How can I add an observer (on change) for each one?

```
$(id).on("change", function(event) {
  alert(id+"__"+$(id).value);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prototype supports event delegation out of the box. [Event.on](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/on/) takes on optional second selector parameter. So in your case:

```
$("product-options-wrapper").on('click', 'select', function(event, element) {

  // This callback will only get fired if you've clicked on a select element that's a descendant of #product-options-wrapper
  // 'element' is the item that matched the second selector parameter, in our case, the select.

  ....

});
```

That parameter can be any CSS selector string:

```
$('my-element').on('click', '.some-class', function(event, element) { ... });
```

---

Check out [Element.select](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/select/), too. That will condense the code in your original question down to essentially one line:

```
$("product-options-wrapper").select('select');
```

This one seems kind of confusing because your selector string is 'select' (you want all SELECT elements under #product-options-wrapper). You could also do:

```
$$('#product-options-wrapper select');
```

These both return an array of matched elements.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

That should do. Please post your html or even better a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) if you need more help.

```
$(function(){
    $('#product-options-wrapper select').on("change", function(e) {
       alert(id+"__"+$(this).val());
    });
});
```

I guess you forgot the `.` at the beginning of product-options-wrapper to indicate its a class? Or is it really a tag?

Comment: the "product-options-wrapper" is the ID of a DIV.

Comment: the first code check this div and find all the <select> in there. its workin !

Comment: I updated my code. It will execute on window load, adding an change handler to each select inside your div and should alert if you change one of your select fields. And with way less code. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: i got this Erreur whene i run it ! 
Erreur : TypeError: $("#product-options-wrapper select") is null

Comment: Question is tagged [prototypejs], not [jquery]

Comment: Yes but he is using jQuery as well and this is the easiest way to achieve it. The selected answer is using jQuery too.

Answer (score 0):

You only need a click handler on the div (in other words, use [event delegation](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/))

```
var tab = $("product-options-wrapper");
tab.on('click',function(e){
  e = e || event;
  if ( /^select$/i.test((e.target || e.srcElement || {}).tagName) ){
    //do stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: ok thx, how can i get the ID and the VALUE of the SELECT changed??